# change width of UIAlertView in iPad

Tags: iphone, uialertview

Is there any way to change the frame of the UIAlertView in iPhone or iPad. I tried changing the frame in the following delegate method`- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView;`

but even then the width of the Alertview remained unchanged. And I think a small  Alertview in iPad will not make sense. And I guess there must be a way to achieve it, at least in iPad.

Thanks, 
krishnan.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this? Just curious, lot of answers here, three years gone by... etc.

Answer (score 8):

Hmm, this code works fine (except, when you are trying to decrease size - cause in this case you can get some bad rendering):

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    alertView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
}
```

Maybe, you forgot to set `UIAlertView`'s delegate with something like `someAlertView.delegate = self;`

*UPDATE ↓*

codepart:

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil
        otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    alert.delegate = self;
    [alert show];
}

- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    alertView.frame = CGRectMake(5.f, 1.f, 100.f, 200.f);
}
```

Result (on my iPod): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6455784/alert_view_frame.png

Comment: I did set the delegate. The height of the AlertView changed but not the width. Did it really work for you?

Comment: Yes. But, when the view's width was less then necessary for correct text displaying (rendering), the view's background frame was rendered badly (left part of the frame rectangle was rounded, but right was not).

Comment: Can you confirm your solution works? astalapista says it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

this is the solution your looking for if you simply want to change the width of the standard UIAlertView with a large text field and one ok button. In my case I just wanted an alert with a large amount of text. And have that text all visible without having to scroll the textview.
The trick is you have to change the width of all/some of the views inside.
No guarantees this will pass app approval. They might find UIAlertTextView and reject it.

```
#define ALERT_VIEW_WIDTH 600
#define ALERT_PADDING 20
-(void) willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView*) alertView
{
    id thing;
    int center=alertView.center.x-ALERT_VIEW_WIDTH/2;
    for (thing in alertView.subviews)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [[thing class] description]);
        if([[[thing class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIAlertTextView"])
        {
            UIView* v=(UIView*)thing;
            v.frame=CGRectMake(v.frame.origin.x+ALERT_PADDING, v.frame.origin.y, ALERT_VIEW_WIDTH-ALERT_PADDING*3, 250);
        }
        if([[[thing class] description] isEqualToString:@"UIThreePartButton"])
        {
            UIView* v=(UIView*)thing;
            v.frame=CGRectMake(v.frame.origin.x+ALERT_PADDING, v.frame.origin.y, ALERT_VIEW_WIDTH-ALERT_PADDING*3, v.frame.size.height);
        }
    }
    alertView.frame=CGRectMake(center, alertView.frame.origin.y, ALERT_VIEW_WIDTH, 360);

}
```

Comment: Did you got the app approved in which you used the same ?

Answer (score 3):

No textfields are present on my alertview, still when i set frame or use transform the view's background frame was rendered badly in the device. This thing will work fine in simulator only.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a old question but I was facing the same problem and the answers here helped me.
I needed to enlarge the title and message text fields in order to accomodate more text on the iPad.

What I did is implement the UIAlertView *willPresentAlertView:* delegate method and add two UILabel objects to serve as title and message. I was than able to configure the frame size and origin of these two labels. After obtaining the desired size for the text fields I resize the alertview in order to accomodate the new text. Then I iterate through the subviews of the alertview to find the button and adjust it's frame.

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {

        // add a new label and configure it to replace the title
        UILabel *tempTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,20,350, 20)];
        tempTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tempTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        tempTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        tempTitle.numberOfLines = 1;
        tempTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18];
        tempTitle.text = alertView.title;
        alertView.title = @"";
        [alertView addSubview:tempTitle];
        [tempTitle release];

        // add another label to use as message 
        UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 50, 350, 200)];
        tempLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tempLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        tempLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        tempLabel.numberOfLines = 20;
        tempLabel.text = alertView.message;
        [alertView addSubview:tempLabel];

        // method used to resize the height of a label depending on the text height
        [self setUILabel:tempLabel withMaxFrame:CGRectMake(10,50, 350, 300) withText:alertView.message];
        alertView.message = @"";

        // set the frame of the alert view and center it
        alertView.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(alertView.frame) - (370 - CGRectGetWidth(alertView.frame))/2 , 
                                     alertView.frame.origin.y, 
                                     370, 
                                     tempLabel.frame.size.height + 120);


        // iterate through the subviews in order to find the button and resize it
        for( UIView *view in alertView.subviews)
        {
            if([[view class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIControl class]])
            {
                view.frame = CGRectMake   (view.frame.origin.x+2,
                                           tempLabel.frame.origin.y + tempLabel.frame.size.height + 10,
                                           370 - view.frame.origin.x *2-4,
                                           view.frame.size.height);
            }
        }

        [tempLabel release];
}
```

And the method used for resizing the label:

```
    - (void)setUILabel:(UILabel *)myLabel withMaxFrame:(CGRect)maxFrame withText:(NSString *)theText{
    CGSize stringSize = [theText sizeWithFont:myLabel.font constrainedToSize:maxFrame.size lineBreakMode:myLabel.lineBreakMode];
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(myLabel.frame.origin.x, 
                               myLabel.frame.origin.y, 
                               myLabel.frame.size.width, 
                               stringSize.height
                               );
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way of doing this but it worked for me.

Comment: Yes It was working before ios7, but for IOS 7 it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use This Method with respective height and width for iPhone and iPad respectively:

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    [alertView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 20, 300, 420)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This small edit works for SWIFT 5:

```swift
let constraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(
          item: alertController.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute:
          NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
alertController.view.addConstraint(constraintHeight)

let constraintWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(
          item: alertController.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute:
          NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 400)
alertController.view.addConstraint(constraintWidth)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).