# Change the width of UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, ios-simulator, cocos2d-iphone

I would like to reduce the width of an alertview. I tried to

1.set a frame.
2.CGAffineTransformMakeScale to scale the alertview
I was able to reduce the width using any of the above methods in the simulator but in the device as a result of the transform an alertview with a different shape appeared.

Please provide a way to reducde the width of the alertview without distorting the shape of the alertview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is give in this thread [change width of UIAlertView in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763713/change-width-of-uialertview-in-ipad)

Comment: may be i didn't try it out on device.